# Delegate property to another property

Tags: kotlin

Can you delegate a property to another property in Kotlin? I have the following code:

```
class SettingsPage {
  lateinit var tagCharacters: JTextField
  lateinit var tagForegroundColorChooser: ColorPanel
  lateinit var tagBackgroundColorChooser: ColorPanel

  var allowedChars: String
    get() = tagCharacters.text
    set(value) = tagCharacters.setText(value)

  var tagForegroundColor by tagForegroundColorChooser
  var tagBackgroundColor by tagBackgroundColorChooser
}
```

In order to get property delegation, I declare the following two extension functions:

```
  operator fun ColorPanel.getValue(a: SettingsPage, p: KProperty<*>) = selectedColor
  operator fun ColorPanel.setValue(a: SettingsPage, p: KProperty<*>, c: Color?) { selectedColor = c }
```

However, what I would like to write is something like the following:

```
class SettingsPage {
  lateinit var tagCharacters: JTextField
  lateinit var tagForegroundColorChooser: ColorPanel
  lateinit var tagBackgroundColorChooser: ColorPanel

  var allowedChars: String by Alias(tagCharacters.text)
  var tagForegroundColor by Alias(tagForegroundColorChooser.selectedColor)
  var tagBackgroundColor by Alias(tagBackgroundColorChooser.selectedColor)
}
```

Is this possible to do Kotlin? How do I write the class `Alias`?

Answer (score 23):

**UPD:** Since Kotlin 1.4, the standard library includes the necessary extensions that [allow this out of the box](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#delegating-to-another-property):

```kotlin
class MyClass(var memberInt: Int, val anotherClassInstance: ClassWithDelegate) {
    var delegatedToMember: Int by this::memberInt
    var delegatedToTopLevel: Int by ::topLevelInt
    
    val delegatedToAnotherClass: Int by anotherClassInstance::anotherClassInt
}
var MyClass.extDelegated: Int by ::topLevelInt
```

---

Yes, it's possible: you can use a [bound callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#bound-callable-references) for a property that you store in the alias, and then the `Alias` implementation will look like this:

```
class Alias<T>(val delegate: KMutableProperty0<T>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = 
        delegate.get()

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        delegate.set(value) 
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
class Container(var x: Int)

class Foo {
    var container = Container(1)
    var x by Alias(container::x)
}
```

To reference a property of the same instance, use `this::someProperty`.

Comment: Is it possible to define an extension function on `KProperty0`, where the usage is simply `var x by container::x`?

Comment: @Breandan: `operator fun <T> KProperty0<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = get(); operator fun <T> KMutableProperty0<T>.setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) = set(value);`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this does not support delegation to synthetic properties from Java classes. Defining these extensions on the original example with `var tagBackgroundColor by tagBackgroundColorChooser::selectedColor` results in an error, `Unsupported [reference to the synthetic extension property for a Java get/set method]`.

Comment: @hotkey Your answer's definition of `Alias` does not work for the same reason as mentioned above.

Comment: Works with synthetic:

```fun <T> syntheticPropertyDelegate(destinationPropertyBlock: () -> KMutableProperty0<T>): ReadWriteProperty<View, T> {
    return object : ReadWriteProperty<View, T> {
        override fun getValue(thisRef: View, property: KProperty<*>): T {
            return destinationPropertyBlock().get()
        }
        override fun setValue(thisRef: View, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
            destinationPropertyBlock().set(value)
        }
    }
}```

Usage:
```var userName: CharSequence? by syntheticPropertyDelegate { user_channel_view::userName }```

Answer (score 3):

Follow-up, if you would like to see support for property references in Kotlin, please vote and track this issue for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8658